# Undefined subroutine call while copying files

Tags: perl

I am trying to copy the files from one folder to another using perl.These folders will be passed as an input by the user.

Example:

```
First folder : \\filesource\source 
Target folder: \\filesource\destination
```

but while copying the files, I am getting below mentioned error :

```
Undefined subroutine &main::Copy called
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use File::Copy;
my $errExitCode_const = 1;
unless( @ARGV == 2){
    print "$0 - requires 2 input parameters and only " .
        @ARGV ." are being passed. \n$!\n";
    exit( $errExitCode_const );
}

## Get parameters
my $source_dir  = $ARGV[0];
my $dest_dir  = $ARGV[1];

## Initiazise Variables
my @files;
my $file_name;
my $filename;
my $dt_stamp;

## Change the directory path.
chdir($source_dir);

# Reads all files from the input directory.
@files = <*>;

foreach $filename(@files) {   
   $file_name =  substr($filename,0,19);
   print "\nfile_name:" . $file_name;
   if($file_name =~ "PROVIDER_KEY_IN_IGF") {
        Copy($file_name,$dest_dir.$file_name)
            or die "Failed to copy $file_name :$!\n";
    }
  #Delete input file #unlink($filename);
} ## End foreach
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs for [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)? You should be using `copy($file_name, $dest_dir.$file_name);`

Comment: `File::Copy::copy` might also do the trick too.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)

> `The File::Copy module provides two basic functions, copy and move , which are useful for getting the contents of a file from one place to another.`

You need to use the functions provided by the module, not call the module by name.

This line:

```
File::Copy($file_name,$dest_dir.\$file_name)
    or die "Failed to copy $file_name :$!\n";
```

should therefore be

```
copy($file_name, $dest_dir.$file_name) or die ...;
```

If you want to add a slash before the file name, you will need to either put `$dest_dir` and `$file_name` in quotes or use quotes around the slash, i.e.:

```
copy($file_name, $dest_dir."\".$file_name)
```

Comment: I had updated my code and tried to execute the same but still I am getting the same error..

Comment: @Praveenks Your updated code still has `Copy()`, not `copy()` (all lower case) as @i-alarmed-alien wrote. `File::Copy` (mixed case) is the name of the module which provides the function `copy` (lower case).